# 2 Panels added to Frame are one on top of the other

Tags: java, border-layout

I am trying to add to JPanels to JFrame but the second one just go on top of the first one and I can't seem to understand why or how to fix it.

Below is the UI that I try to add.
Thanks a lot,

Rotem

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Maman 13 - Part 2");
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout alignLeftLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5);
    // first row
    Hashtable<Integer, JButton> hashTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JButton>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> buttons = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    addFirstRow(buttons);
    JPanel firstRow = new KeyboardRow(hashTable, buttons);
    firstRow.setLayout(alignLeftLayout);
    f.add(firstRow);
    // second row
    buttons = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    addSecondRow(buttons);
    JPanel secondRow = new KeyboardRow(hashTable, buttons);
    secondRow.setLayout(alignLeftLayout);
    f.add(secondRow);

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: aren't you setting both panel layout positions as `alignLeftLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

try

```
f.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Comment: I tried what you sayd and it realy helped to put both rows on screen. However, I need them to be one on top of the other. How can I achive that? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Sure, you should set parameters for gridlayout `f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1);` or it might be 1,2. Try both. I don't have a compiler with me right now :)

Comment: @user3557312: Also consider `GridLayout(0, 1)` for a one-column grid with an arbitrary number of rows.

Comment: @trashgod yeah, I forgot to mention that. Those numbers indicate the maximum elements that can be put inrespectively rows and columns. 0 means unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do like

```
f.add(firstRow, BorderLayout.WEST)
```

and

```
f.add(secondRow, BorderLayout.EAST)
```

or something like that.  You are not specifying how to use the BorderLayout scheme you added.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to replace your f.add([something]); lines.

```
f.add(firstRow, BorderPanel.LINE_START);
f.add(secondRow, BorderPanel.LINE_END);
```

This should put the firstRow panel on the left, and the secondRow panel on the right.

This works because a BorderLayout is built to hold up to five panels, as explained here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html

Your existing code just adds the new panels to f, without specifying where they should go.

Comment: What should I do if I want the rows to be one above the other? My purpuse is to create a keyboard view where I have 5 rows and each of them are above the other.